# How to drop row at certain index in every group in GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to drop a row at certain index in every group inside a GroupBy object.

The best I have been able to manage is:

```
import pandas as pd
    
x_train = x_train.groupby('ID')
x_train.apply(lambda x: x.drop([0], axis=0))
```

However, this doesn't work. I have spent a whole day on this to no solution, so have turned to stack.

Edit: A solution for any index value is needed as well

Comment: I have checked 47 stack posts to no avail, trust me when i say this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `cumcount`

```
idx= x_train.groupby('ID').cumcount()
x_train = x_train[idx!=0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had spent nearly the whole day on this. I am forever grateful to you

Comment: just another question, how could I use this approach for any index?

Comment: @AayushPanda if you need remove 1 just do x_train[idx!=1], if both 1 and 0 , x_train[~idx.isin([0,1])]

Comment: but how do I do last one if every df has different row count?

Comment: @AayushPanda idx= x_train.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False), then x_train = x_train[idx!=0], it will reverse the count order ~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) inside the `groupby` is the index numbers are still the same as before the `groupby`. So when using `drop([0])`, only the row that originally had `0` as index will be dropped. In the other groups, there will not be any row with index `0` as long as the index is unique.

If you want to use `drop` then what you can do is to first use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) inside the grouped data:

```
x_train.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index().drop([0]))
```